# Error using count vectoriser and TF-IDF transformer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've written the following code to trasnform some data:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
def transform (data):
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", tokenizer = None, preprocessor = None, stop_words = None)
    clean = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    clean_tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    clean_tfidf = clean_tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(clean)
    return clean_tfidf, clean_tfidf.shape[1]
```

However, when running it on some data it produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 169, in <module>
    X, y = process(directory, filename)
  File "...", line 132, in process
    tr_abstract, abstractN = transform(pre_abstract)
  File "...", line 77, in transform
    clean = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 752, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 238, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 118, in decode
    raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You should use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) which is as mentioned in documentation, equivalent to CountVectorizer followed by TfidfTransformer, instead of using them individually.

Answer (score 2):

Your data have missing value, the following code can reproduce the error

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
import numpy as np

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", tokenizer=None, preprocessor=None, stop_words=None)
clean = vectorizer.fit_transform([u'i am shane', np.nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when using `tfidf` and `tfidf.fit_transform`. None of the other answers here worked, so I ran

```
df['data'] = df['data'].astype(str)
```

And then, it worked! Do try this